# Migrating to local server

Tags: migration, localhost

I have my wordpress site on my local server at the following path :

```
wordpress-4.2.3\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme
```

and the url to access my local site is:

```
http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress/
```

Now I need to migrate it to another local server, for this I have imported database successfully and copied `wp-content` folder and placed it in my project's folder as below:

```
my-project-name\wp-content\themes\mytheme
```

and also changed `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`  which is initially `http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress/` to `http://local-server-ip/my-project-name/` but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide more information on this one @nomeer. Stuff such as have the permissions been rightly set? Is the codebase in the document root of the local-server-ip machine?

Comment: where did you change the home and site URLs, in the database or in the wp-config.php file? Have you created the user in your config.php file as a user on your database server?